# What is subvector, submatrix and dictionaries?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

On "[A pivoting algorithm for convex hulls and vertex enumeration of arrangements and polyhedra](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02293050)" by David Avis & Komei Fukuda Section 2

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, with columns indexed by the set $E = \{1, 2. . . . , n\}$. Fix distinct indices f and 9 of E. Consider the system of equations
> $$Ax = 0, x_g = 1. (2.1)$$
> For any $J \subseteq E$, $x_J$ denotes the subvector of $x$ indexed by $J$, and $A_J$ denotes the submatrix of $A$ consisting of columns indexed by $J$. A basis $B$ for (2.1) is a subset
> of $E$ of cardinality $m$ containing $f$ but not $g$, for which $A_B$ is nonsingular. We are
> only concerned with systems (2.1) that have at least one basis, and assume this for
> the rest of the paper. Given any basis B, we can transform (2.1) into the dictionary
> $$x_B=-A_B^{-1} A_N x_N = \bar{A} x_N. (2.2)$$
> where $N = E - B$ is the co-basis and $\bar A$ denotes $-A_B^{-1} A_N$. $\bar A$ is called the coefficient matrix of the dictionary, with rows indexed by $B$ and columns indexed by $N$, so that $\bar{A} = (\bar{a}_{ij}:i\in B , J\in N)$. Note that the co-basis always contains the index $g$.

I don't quite understand what the paper was talking about. I tried to google the "subvector" which seemed to suggest multiple different definitions: [Is sub-vector an established mathematical entity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328417/is-sub-vector-an-established-mathematical-entity). The submatrix was also not defined.

Could you explain a bit what the subvector or submatrix was defined and why it was the case, please? Also, how does $x_g=1$, how does it exist for a random matrix?

Comment: The submatrices of $(a_{i,j})_{i\in I,j\in J}$ are $(a_{i,j})_{i\in K,j\in L}$ for any $K\subset I,L\subset J.$ Since a vector is a particular matrix, its subvectors are its submatrices. More explicitely: the subvectors of  $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ are $(v_i)_{i\in K}$ for any $K\subset I.$